# Do method/parameter names affect how much memory something takes on the stack?

Tags: java, memory, stack

Do things like method names or parameter names have any effect on how much memory an entry takes up on the stack?

I know that primitive arguments like `int`s do take up memory, but I'd like to know if I'd get any memory savings, however minuscule, from naming my methods and parameter names concisely, or if I should give them long enough names to describe what they do.

```
public static int convertSomeIntegerValueToSomeOtherIntegerValueByMethodOfDividingTheOriginalIntegerByTwoAndRoundingTheOutputBecauseItIsAnInteger(int veryVerboseIntegerValueWithAVeryLongParameterNameSoItCanBeDividedByTwo){
    return veryVerboseIntegerValueWithAVeryLongParameterNameSoItCanBeDividedByTwo/2;
}
public static int divTwo(int a){
    return a/2;
}
```

Is there any difference between these two methods other than file size of the source code?

Also, do these method names make the compiled code bigger?

Comment: I'm a newbie here, so if you downvote please leave a comment as to why. Thanks!

Comment: For your last question, why don't you just put these in a class, compile and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This has no impact on memory usage at all.

Things on the stack are resolved purely based on their "position" relative to the stack frame.

Method and class names are of course stored somewhere (in the class meta-data), but this does not affect memory usage (except for loading the class itself -- the *class* mind you, it does not affect memory usage of creating instances).

Parameter names and variable names are not stored at all unless you enable debug symbols during compilation.

The only things that take up memory (on the heap, not on the stack) at runtime are things like keys in hashtables (but even there with interned string constants, the memory effect should be miniscule as well).

> Also, do these method names make the compiled code bigger?

Yes. But it does not matter in the grand scheme of things.